# MSMQ Trigger and Rule API for C#

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I need C# API to handle Microsoft Messaging Queue(MSMQ) triggers and rules.Can anybody let me know where I can get this API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed MSMQ. Using VS2013 you will find the MSMQ API in the System.Messaging namespace. You may also want to use the System.Transactions namespace as well